# How can you return the number of times an item is saved to a specific array index?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a class called LetterCounter. This class processes strings by turning the letters of a string into chars and adding them to an array called counts[] with 26 positions, with 0 corresponding to 'a' and 25 corresponding to 'z'. This is what the process() method looks like.

```
    public class LetterCounter
{
    private static final int[] counts = new int[26];

/**
 * Method converts letters in a String into index positions in an array.
 * 0 corresponds to a, 1 to b, 2 to c, etc.
 * 
 * @param someString A String of letters
 */
public void process(String someString)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < someString.length(); i++)
    {
        char myChar = Character.toLowerCase(someString.charAt(i));
        int index = (myChar - 'a');
        if ((index >= 0) && (index <= 25))
        {
            counts[index]++;
        }
    }
}
```

I have a method in this class that I call getMostCommon() which iterates over the array and determines which position has the most stored items. It looks like this:

```
/**
 * Method finds the letter which appears most often.
 */
public char getMostCommon()
{
    int max = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++)
    {
        if(counts[i] > max)
        {
            max = i;
        }
    }

    char c = Character.toLowerCase((char)(max + 'a'));
    return c;
}
```

Here is the test class. I expect 't' to be the most common letter, but the method returns 'o' as the most common letter.

```
public class CounterDemo1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    //Constructs new LetterCounter called cc
    LetterCounter cc = new LetterCounter();

    //The letters in these strings will be processed into array index positions.
    cc.process("Bojack hates the troops");
    cc.process("Peanut butter is one word");
    cc.process("Use a pretty font");

    //Demonstrates printHistogram()
    cc.printHistogram();
    //Demonstrates getCount()
    System.out.println("There are " + cc.getCount('b') + " b's.");
    //Demonstrates getToalLetters()
    System.out.println("There are " + cc.getTotalLetters() + " total letters.");
    //Demonstrates getMostCommon()
    System.out.println("The most common letter is: " + cc.getMostCommon());
}
```

}

Comment: add the language tag, Java or?

Comment: The issue isn't with that function. Post a complete program (a [mcve]) along with the input you provide to the program and actual along with expected output (you should always do this).

Comment: Seems that the problem could be on the way you count the number of characters (the way you create `counts` array). Could you please add that code as well?

Comment: Is `max` supposed to be the number of times the most frequent letter occurs or the index of the most frequent letter?  Your code seems to be inconsistent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to store the value of the maximun character frequency so far: *max* **and** the current character index: *i*.

You are comparing *max* with the frequency of the character *i*:`if(counts[i] > max)` and then assigning the value of *i* to *max*: `max = i;`

You probably want to do this:

```
public char getMostCommon()
{
     int max = 0;
     int current_index = 0; // current character index
     for(int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++)
     {
          if(counts[i] > max)
          {
               max = counts[i]; // Getting the value of the frequency
               current_index = i; // And the value of the character index
          }
      }
      // Finally parsing the index
      char c = Character.toLowerCase((char)(current_index + 'a'));
      return c;
}
```

Comment: Your comment slashes are backwards; should be `//`

Comment: This is it. Thank you. I see how my code was incorrect now. I was using the array index as the value for max so once a position with a value higher than the total number of letters available was saved as max, the next position wasn't being counted even if it had more letters.

Comment: I think maintaining `max_index` is enough. You can use `if (counts[i] > counts[max_index])`.